# How to bind multiple properties in one calculate in GoJS?

Tags: javascript, gojs

I have a simple demo like the one below:

```
const calcProperty = (data) => {
  //Some complex calculate
  return {
    text: '...',
    stroke: "..."
  }
}
const calcText = (data) => {
  return calcProperty(data).text;
}
const calcStroke = (data) => {
  return calcProperty(data).stroke;
}


$(go.TextBlock, {
    text: 'refresh', //Default
    stroke: 'red', // Default
  },
  new go.Binding("text", "", calcText),
  new go.Binding("stroke", "", calcStroke),
  ),
```

As you can see, the complex calculations have to run twice.
Is that anyway I can do something like this, and it automatic to apply to properties?

```
  new go.Binding("dynamic or something", "", (data) => {
      //Some complex calculate
      return {
        text: '...',
        stroke: "..."
      }
  }),
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set the properties, once calculated, on the Node's `data` object, and also set a flag.

```js
const calcProperty = (data) => {
  if (data.calculated) return data; // already run
  data.calculated = true;
  //Some complex calculations that ALSO set:
  data.text = "...";
  data.stroke = "...";
  return data;
}
```

Of course, you will need to handle cache invalidation if you go this route.

**Note also that empty-string bindings re-run every time any of the data changes.** If this is intended to be a one-time thing it shouldn't be a data binding at all, it should be computed before the node data is even added to the model, and the data bindings should be simple bindings instead.